# how to create a button, pressable or a touchable opacity that redirects us to a website using react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

hey everyone I am newbie at react native and i want to know how to create a button, touchableopacity or a pressable that redirects us to a website using react native

Answer (score 0):

Simply, there ir a module from React Native called [Linking Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) where you can use the function `openURL` where the input argument is just your website link.

Full example:

```
// Import
import { Linking, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'


// Component's code
<TouchableOpacity
 style={{
  width: 100,
  height: 60,
  backgroundColor: "red"
 }}
 onPress={() => Linking.openURL("https://stackoverflow.com")}
>
  <Text>
   Go to my website
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This function redirect to the default external browser of the device. If you want to use the native WebView check this library [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview) (which few versions ago was included on react-native library)

Comment: no still it is not working getting error can't find variable linking

Comment: Make sure you import the modules (it is on the top of the example)
`import { Linking, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'`

Comment: Thank you so much jesmoava

Comment: Can you change the answer as useful @shubham ?

Comment: Yes i will do that